# Extending a probability measure to the sigma field obtained by adjoining a new set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $P$ is a probability measure on a sigma field $\mathcal{B}$ and suppose $A\not\in\mathcal{B}$.  Let $$\mathcal{B}_{1}=\sigma(\mathcal{B},A)$$
be the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{B}$ and $A$.  Show that $P$ has an extension to a probability measure $P_{1}$ on $\mathcal{B}_{1}$.  [This is problem 4 in section 2.6 of Resnick's "A Probability Path"].

It seems the only option is to define $P_1(A)=0$ and $P_1(B\cap A^{c})=P(B)$ but I cannot see that this is well-defined; for example, can it happen that $B\cap A$ belongs to $\mathcal{B}$?

Added later: Turns out this has been already asked:
[Extension of measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919261/extension-of-measures)
and that question suggests that my assumption that $P_{1}(A)=0$ is wrong; but
there's no accepted answer to that question, either.

Comment: But there is an answer... (Frankly, this fixation on "accepted" answers escapes me.)

Comment: I fleshed out the answer to the cited problem.